# Windows NFS user mapping issue when working with NetApp clustered ONTAP

Tags: mapping, windows-server-2008-r2, nfs, user-permissions, netapp

I have an issue with user mapping while using NFS export from NetApp and trying to mount it on a windows using the NFS client feature.

I have a qtree exported from the NetApp using NFS and I installed the NFS client on Windows (via server manager - roles - file server). I am able to mount, read and write as anonymous user - the problem is in the user mapping.

I tried to add to the registry at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default the two DWOD values AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid and gave them the desired UID and GID in decimal form and restarted the service.

While this trick worked fine on an NFS export which I exported on my RHEL 6.3 and also on a 7 mode NetApp but it seems the thing doesn't work the same here.

Somehow when I used shownount -e on the RHEL or 7 mode it showed the exports and when I tried on the clustered ONTAP vserver it only shows the / (and even though the mount command completes successfully when writing the path)

Any suggestions?

Details:
Client is windows server 2008 R2 x64 bit program (services for NFS)
Server is NetApp clustered ONTAP 8.2.3p4

Edit:
I also tried user-mapping at server side using both vserver name-mapping win-unix  to  index 1.
And added a rule to the export-policy:
10.0.0.1 (I changed the IP for security reasons)
User is to which anonymous users are mapped to: 1000

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently a good old reboot solved the problem (reboot to the client). Actually I tried to uninstall and reinstall client for NFS and windows cried out for a reboot before it could reinstall it.

After I reinstalled it just worked. I tried to narrow it down to see what was the solution.

It was the registry tweak: once I removed the DWORD values it stopped the mapping and worked again when I recreated them. It also continued working after I changed the export policy to anon 65543.